# More efficient way to call model via function for api endpoint?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

***Is there a more efficient way to call an sklearn model via function?  Trying to use this to deploy an api endpoint for rest api call***

I want my output to be `{prediction: "...", "class_0_proba": "...", "class_1_proba": "..."}` as dictionary/json schema structure.

***Also, how could I modify function to allow multiple json/dict rows? ... currently my code can only accept 1 sample row for testing***

I am currently using `json.dumps()` then `json.loads()` to  convert the string back into a dict.  This doesn't seem to be the best approach.

```py
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# sklearn classification model
model = joblib.load("model.pkl")

import json

# function
def preds(dict):
    df = pd.DataFrame([dict])
    result = model.predict(df)
    class_0_p= model.predict_proba(df)[0][0]
    class_1_p= model.predict_proba(df)[0][1]
    j = json.dumps({"prediction": result[0],
                      "class0_prob": class_0_p,
                      "class1_prob": class_1_p})
    j = json.loads(j)
    return j

# testing function on sample observation
preds({
  "c1": "raw text as a feature",
  "c2": "another raw text col as a feature",
  "c3": 0,
  "c4": 0,
  "c5": 0,
  "c6": "text value",
  "c7": "some text value",
  "c8": "flag",
  "c9": "another flag",
  "c10": 0,
  "c11": 0,
  "c12": 0,
  "c13": 0
})

# output from function
{'prediction': 'class_0_label',
 'class0_prob': 0.6784582619132933,
 'class1_prob': 0.3215417380867065}
```